# Text File not Created in ' if ' Statement

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x

I am working on a little program with is able to write and load .txt files.

I am facing an issue, where the .txt file is not created when my save () function is in a "if" loop. I did used the computer's search function just in case that it was created somewhere else. Nope, nothing on the .txt file came out.

For you information, I am coding in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 (Community), and using Windows 8.

Here are the codes:

```
def save (dic, filename):
    out_file = open (filename, "wt")

    key_list = []
    for i in dic.keys():
        key_list.append (i)
        key_list.sort ()

    for i in range(len(key_list)):
        key = key_list [i]
        out_file.write (key + "," + dic [key] + "\n")

    out_file.close ()


filename = "dictionary.txt"
count = input ("Save (0) or Load (1): ")

if count == 0:
    dic = {}

    dic["1"] = "11"
    dic ["2"] = "22"
    dic ["3"] = "33"
    dic ["4"] = "44"
    dic ["5"] = "55"

    save (dic, filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` function returns a string. Since count is a string, `count == 0` is always false. This is because the string `'0'` and the number `0` are not equal.

You have two options here. You can either convert the count to an integer with `count = int(input('...'))` and not touch your condition, or you can compare count with the string representation of 0 (`count == '0'`).